# ORACLE DATABASE SYNCING

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g, database-replication

I have a local and remote oracle database table. The remote table is updated whenever new user(s) is registered. Now I am using a java scheduler to query the remote database every 30 minutes and updating the newly added values in my local table. It will be really good if both these tables are in sync that is, if a new entry is added to the remote table then it should be reflected in my local table also. Can anyone suggest a efficient way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. to create a database link between the local and the remote database
2. to create a materialized view to replicate the remote table to the local table.

See https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/materialized-views